# Problems with long path in TFS Team Build when CreatePackageOnPublish is set to true.

Tags: msbuild, tfsbuild

We have a problem by build because of long path created by TFS Team Build when parameter *CreatePackageOnPublish* is set to *true*.

In directory *PackageTmp* (see picture later) the package is stored, but I don't understand why this directory structure is necessary and how it can be customized.

The problem is that the deployment or new TFS build generates error because of long path.

I will be grateful for your help.

Regards

Anton Kalcik

This is the (anonymised) tree structure created by TFS Team Build:

[image]

Comment: Can you map a drive to a folder in that structure that will give you a path that doesn't hit the 256 character path limit?

Comment: I've the same problem ... but couldn't find any solution :-(

Comment: @PabloC: Don't unterstand what do you mean...

Comment: @Konrad: Use use MSBuild Argument CreatePackageOnPublish=False if possible

Comment: @AKa I misunderstood your problem. Are you creating the package because you want to archive it for backup or are you publishing it? The folder structure seems to reflect the structure of your solution. Have you tried specifying a property using "/p:PackageLocation=\\DesiredPathHere"

Comment: @PabloC: I don't really need to have the package for any reason. Was only interessting why the packaging create the directory structure recursively... Thank you for your hint!

Comment: No worries. If it works out, you might want to answer your own question.

Comment: Oh there is a parameter to define the package location? This seems to work ... but is there any documentation of all possible parameters in this context and its allowed values?

Comment: @Konrad not that I've found. It would be a useful resource eh?

Comment: @Konrad: Here the book, pretty good documentation. http://tinyurl.com/6p99gdz

Comment: @AKa thank you for the info with the book :-)

Comment: That book, just like the sketchy online documentation for MSBuild, stops short of useful, though it's better than nothing.  It does not cover the PackageLocation argument, for instance: try "searching inside" from that Amazon link.

Answer (score 2):

An easy workaround is to create the *'PackageTmp'* folder as a .zip file. To do so right-click on your Project from VS and select *'Package/Publish Settings'*. In the *'Web Deployment Package Settings'* tick the *'Create deployment package as a .zip file'*.

Another workaround is to add the following parameter on your command that runs on Tfs build:

```
MSBuild.exe WebProjectName.cs /p:Configuration="Release";DeployOnBuild=true;DeployTarget=Package; _PackageTempDir=C:\Package
```

The **_PackageTempDir=C:\Package** will create the following output path:

..\WebProjectName_Package\Archive\Content\**C_C\Package**\..