# Publishing of Web Project via msbuild.exe results in very long folder

Tags: tfs, build, msbuild, directory

I am building and publishing a single web project, which is in a big solution. 
I start the msbuild.exe from a cmd file, which is invoked by a TeamBuild Process:

```
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319    MSBuild.exe /p:Configuration=Release /p:DeployOnBuild=True /p:CreatePackageOnPublish=true /T:Package "%~dp0%xxx.Project1.csproj"
```

In the project settings of project1.csproj under Web deployment package setting:

Location where package will be created: $(SourcesDirectoryOfProject)\..\..\..\..\bin\xxx.Project1

This works very well, but the problem is, that the folder named "Archive" in "..\..\..\..\bin\xxx.Project1" becomes very long. I have to click through 16 subfolders, until I am at the actually Web-files like Web.config and so on. Under the Archive folder are subfolders that seem to represent the hole folder-structure to the temporary drop folder, where the files for publishing are created in first:

```
...\Archive\Content\D_C\Builds\9\TeamProjectName\BigProject\Sources\BigProject\Main\Source\SolutionName\ProjectName\obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\bin
```

And finally under PackageTemp I find my Web Files. The REAL problem with that is, that the foldernames for some files become to long - so I cannot delete them correctly and the TeamBuild crashes, because it cannot empty the Builds-Folder before compiling and doing computer stuff.

The best would be to have an option where I can tell the msbuild.exe (or maybe in the project-settings) where it should dump the WebProject Files (- the files I mean are the Folders: App_Code, bin, Configuration; Files: global.asax, some xamlx and Web.config)

So - how can I drop the WebProject data to another specified path?

Best regards

Sebastian

Comment: Take a look at a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862339/problems-with-long-path-in-tfs-team-build-when-createpackageonpublish-is-set-to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was a wrong MSBuild.exe command. I use this one now, which only deploys the web service to a specific local folder without any IIS needed:

```
MSBuild.exe /target:Build;PipelinePreDeployCopyAllFilesToOneFolder /p:Configuration=Release;_PackageTempDir=%binfolder% "projectfile.csproj"
```

It also doesn't do this long folder names stuff.